# getting the color of pixels on the screen in Python3.x

Tags: colors, get, python-3.x, screen

I want to get the color of pixels on the screen in Python3.x. (example x,y)
I work on windows. and using tkinter.
But, It can't use PIL in Python 3.x.

How can i do this.
Thank you.

Comment: You need a GUI library of some sort, like wx, GTK, KDE, or wind32 or whatever the OSX one is called. Each of them would have different ways of doing this.

Comment: Not a clue, but you should include that information in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PIL on Python3.x; there is a [binary installer for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil). The code might not work as is both on Python2.x and Python3.x:

```
try: import Image         # Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image # Python 3.x
```

You could capture an area of the screen using an analog of [`grab()` method](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot/tree/master/pyscreenshot/plugins).

Comment: I can not found PIL for python3.x.

Comment: @user1161599: click [the above link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil).