# How do I check if a given point is inside the polygon python

Tags: python, polygon

May I ask how can code using python to check if a given points is within the polygon I drawn using turtle?

The polygon is drawn using a list of coordinates.

Comment: See if this helps:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer on Wikipedia with very elegant solutions, implement one to your liking.

here: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#:%7E:text=One%20simple%20way%20of%20finding,an%20even%20number%20of%20times.)

Note: you will probably need to implement a `line` class and intersections and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned python, if this is not an homework, you should look at [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/).

Answer (score 0):

One trick that you can use is to fill your polygon with color and then try to detect that color at the given point location.
But the catch is you need to use Tkinter.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381824/turtle-graphics-extract-color-from-onscreenclick) to detect the color at the given location.