# How to get the area of shape filled using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fill, area, fractals

I graphed a fractal shape in Python using turtle, and am trying to get the area of this fractal after a sufficiently high iteration. This fractal is related to the Koch snowflake, for those interested.

I was able to fill in the fractal with black using begin_fill() and end_fill(). I then used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381824/turtle-graphics-extract-color-from-onscreenclick) to get the color of each pixel in a valid range. If it wasn't equal to white, then I added one to the count. This solution works for a small iteration of the fractal. However, it takes an exorbitant amount of time when trying to go to a higher iteration.

Here is my code for the fractal.

```
def realSnowflake(length, n, s, show = False):
    #n: after n iterations
    #s: number of sides (in Koch snowflake, it is 3)
    #length: starting side length
    turtle.begin_fill()
    a = 360/s
    for i in range(s):
        snowflake(length, n, s) 
        turtle.right(a)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

Here is my code for finding the area.

```
count = 0
canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
for x in range(x1, x2+1): #limits calculated through math
    for y in range(y2, y1+1):
        if get_pixel_color(x, y, canvas) != "white":
            count += 1
```

I want to be able to find the area of this fractal faster. It takes the most amount of time not in graphing the fractal, but in the double for loop of x and y. I think if there is a way to find the area while turtle is filling, this would be optimal.

Comment: Finding the area while the turtle is painting a fractal isn't likely to be more efficient that calculating it in one go off of the end result. However, the complexity of the image drawn shouldn't affect the time it takes to count black pixels, since the same number of pixels has to be accessed and compared for any image - so I think your problem is in code you're not sharing here. Where are you calling this code? And what is the `snowflake` function in the `realSnowflake` function? Perhaps you should share a minimal, verifiable and complete example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And like I said in my comment, computing during graphing is highly unlikely to improve performance. Like you also said in your question, the performance appears to get worse when you draw more complex fractals, which makes no sense given the solution you've presented - it's therefore likely to conclude the problem is in the rest of your code. But perhaps your problem isn't a coding problem, but a communication one.

Answer (score 0):

> the complexity of the image drawn shouldn't affect the time it takes
>   to count black pixels

Unfortunately, in this case it does.  If we lookup an [earlier source of the `get_pixel_color()` code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40313937/5771269), we find the telling text, "is slow".  But it's worse than that, it actually slows down!

This code is built atop `canvas.find_overlapping()` which is looking for high level objects that sit over X,Y.  In the case of tkinter filling an object for turtle, there is *overlap*, up to three layers in the code below. This increases as the factal gets more complex.  Here's my code to demonstrate this:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import floor, ceil
from time import time

def koch_curve(turtle, iterations, length):
    if iterations == 0:
        turtle.forward(length)
    else:
        for angle in [60, -120, 60, 0]:
            koch_curve(turtle, iterations - 1, length / 3)
            turtle.left(angle)

def koch_snowflake(turtle, iterations, length):
    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(3):
        koch_curve(turtle, iterations, length)
        turtle.right(120)

    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()

def bounding_box(points):
    x_coordinates, y_coordinates = zip(*points)
    return [(min(x_coordinates), min(y_coordinates)), (max(x_coordinates), max(y_coordinates))]

def get_pixel_color(x, y):
    ids = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)  # This is our bottleneck!

    if ids: # if list is not empty
        index = ids[-1]
        return canvas.itemcget(index, 'fill')

    return 'white' # default color

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.color('red')

canvas = screen.getcanvas()
width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

for iterations in range(1, 7):
    screen.clear()
    turtle.clear()

    screen.tracer(False)

    polygon_start_time = time()
    polygon = koch_snowflake(turtle, iterations, 200)
    polygon_elapsed = round((time() - polygon_start_time) * 1000)  # milliseconds

    screen.tracer(True)

    ((x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_max)) = bounding_box(polygon)
    screen.update()

    # Convert from turtle coordinates to tkinter coordinates
    x1, y1 = floor(x_min), floor(-y_max)
    x2, y2 = ceil(x_max), ceil(-y_min)

    canvas.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2))

    count = 0

    pixel_count_start_time = time()
    for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
        for y in range(y1, y2 + 1):
            if get_pixel_color(x, y) == 'red':
                count += 1
    pixel_count_elapsed = round((time() - pixel_count_start_time) * 1000)

    print(iterations, count, polygon_elapsed, pixel_count_elapsed, ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)))

screen.exitonclick()
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
1 23165 1 493 ((-1, -58), (201, 174))
2 26064 4 1058 ((-1, -58), (201, 174))
3 27358 9 1347 ((-1, -58), (201, 174))
4 28159 29 2262 ((0, -58), (201, 174))
5 28712 104 5925 ((0, -58), (201, 174))
6 28881 449 19759 ((0, -58), (200, 174))
>
```

The fields are as follows:

1. Iterations
2. Pixels counted
3. Time to draw image in ms
4. Time to count pixels in ms
5. Computed bounding box (in tkinter coordinates)

**FINAL ITERATION SCREEN OUTPUT**

[image]

Note that the fractal is drawn by *turtle* but the bounding box is drawn by the underlying *tkinter* to verify that we converted coordinates correctly.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Find an approach that doesn't rely on `find_overlapping()`.  I think the next thing to investigate would be either to convert the canvas to a bitmap image, and pixel count it, or draw a bitmap image in the first place.  There are several discusions on SO about converting a canvas to a bitmap, either directly or indirectly via Postscript.  You could then load in that image and use one of the Python image libraries to count the pixels.  Although more complicated, it should provide a constant time way of counting pixels.  Alternately, there are libraries to draw bitmaps, which you could load into tkinter for visual verfication, but could then pixel count directly.  Good luck!