# How to get color of pixel on Tkinter Canvas in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, colors

Looking for a way to be able to find the color data of a pixel(s) on a Canvas. I'm sort of a beginner to coding, just gauging if this is possible/how to go about this. This is for a project I've been working on, and for part of it, it's necessary to compare the color data of a Canvas to an Image. I know how to find the per pixel color data of an Image, but I haven't found anything for a canvas. I'm using a Tkinter Canvas at the moment, but if it's not possible on that library, I'm open to switching to another library. Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Comment: canvas doesn't have this function - some solution is to use `pillow` and draw on `pillow.Image` (which is bitmap) and it gives access to pixels. And display `pillow.Image` on Canvas.

Comment: other GUIs (like `PyQt`, `PyGTK`, `wxPython`) may give access to pixels but first it may need longer code to get access to they `Canvas` - and finally it can be simpler to draw on Image in this GUI and display this image on Canvas.

Comment: You can use `Pillow.ImageGrab()` to take a screen shot on the point and then get the color from the one-pixel screen shot. See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61292863/5317403).

Answer (score 0):

> Looking for a way to be able to find the color data of a pixel(s) on a Canvas.

Tkinter doesn't provide the ability to do this.

Comment: Gotcha. I did a bit more research and I think a bitmap is the way to go for my specific project. Thanks for the help!